# Display list of mails on the active explorer pane in outlook VSTO

Tags: email, outlook, vsto

I am working on an outlook plugin that will have a list of mail items. What i want to do is display these mail items in the active explorer pane.

Basically many users will be using the plugin. When user x gets an email he will drop it in a a customized pane which will then classify the mail. (I have already developped the drag and drop of mail). I'm currently saving the .msg on a server once dropped.

Now i want to display a list of these mails on the explorer pane. Assuming that i have a list of .msg files how do i make these display on the active explorer pane.

WHAT I've already tried.

```
        OutlookInstance.MAPIFolder inbox = (OutlookInstance.MAPIFolder)application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(OutlookInstance.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        OutlookInstance.MAPIFolder customFolder = null;
        customFolder = (OutlookInstance.MAPIFolder)inbox.Folders.Add("NEWFOLDER", OutlookInstance.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        inbox.Folders["NEWFOLDER"].Display();
```

So the above creates a folder and then i can add the mails in there. However it seems a bit redundant to create folders and then place the mail in there.

Are there any other ways of doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't display emails in an Explorer unless they are present in a folder or Search Folder somewhere.  If these emails only exist as .msg files then you will have to open them from their file path and capture the new Inspector so you can use MailItem.Move to create a copy in a folder (technically it's not moving the file, but .SaveAs isn't relevant).  An alternative is to use Redemption's RDOSession.GetMessageFromMsgFile method.

Once these emails are imported you could possibly use the Explorer.AddToSelection method to make these emails stand out from others that may exist in the same folder.